# php javascript select with default value

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, associative-array

I have some city lists in associative arrays in php. I use javascript "on change" to get the value on each items. I want to set an item as default (I think I am considering using geo location in future).

Here my arrays:

```
// Array lists
$city_array = array(
    array('id' => '1', 'name' => 'Aaaa'),
    array('id' => '2', 'name' => 'Bbbb'),
    array('id' => '3', 'name' => 'Cccc'),
    array('id' => '4', 'name' => 'Dddd'),
    array('id' => '5', 'name' => 'Eeee'),
);
$json_city = json_encode($city_array);
```

And my php function:

```
// Decode
$cities = json_decode($json_city);
function display_cities() {
    global $cities;
    $output = '<select id="citylists" onChange="onSelectCity()">';
    foreach( $cities as $city ) {
        $output .= '<option class="itemcity" value="'.$city->id.'">'.$city->name.'</option>';
    }
    $output .= '</select>';
    $output .= '<script type="text/javascript">
        function onSelectCity() {
            var cityLists = document.getElementById("citylists");
            console.log(cityLists.value);
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            onSelectCity();
        }
    </script>';
    echo $output;
}
```

I want the output is like this (printed in HTML):

```
<select id="citylists">
    <option class="itemcity" value="1">Aaaa</option>
    <option class="itemcity" value="2">Bbbb</option>
    <option class="itemcity" value="3" selected>Cccc</option>
    <option class="itemcity" value="4">Dddd</option>
    <option class="itemcity" value="5">Eeee</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, I set the default value is `<option class="itemcity" value="3" selected>Cccc</option>`.

How can I do that inside dynamic php loop?

Thanks

Comment: Posible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571710/selecting-dynamic-default-value-in-select

Comment: Hi, thank you for reminding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach( $cities as $city ) {
    $selected = ($city->id == 3)?' selected ':null;

    $output .= '<option class="itemcity" value="'.$city->id.'"'.$selected.'>'.$city->name.'</option>';
}
```

By the way, for valid HTML you should change it to selected="selected"